# How to perform a login identification process in the best way?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I have 2 inputs boxes: Public key (user name) and Private key (password). Also I have a hidden warning label.

This is my code (and it's perfectly  working ):

```
<script language="javascript">
function SendLoginData() {
    document.getElementById("LoginErrorLabel").style.display = "none";
    var url = "/DappAccount/CheckAccount";

    $.post(url, { PublicKey: $("#public_key_input").val(), PrivateKey: $("#private_key_input").val() }, function (data) {
        if (data == false) {
            document.getElementById("LoginErrorLabel").style.display = "block";
            return;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "block";
            $("#myform").submit()
        }

    });
}
</script>


<div class="container">
@using (Html.BeginForm("AccountMainPage", "DappAccount", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "myform" }))
{
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.publicKey, new { id = "public_key_input", placeholder = "Ethereum Public Key", required = "required" })
    </div> <br />
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.privateKey, new { id = "private_key_input", placeholder = "Ethereum Private Key", required = "required", type = "password" })
    </div> <br />
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
               <img id="loader" style="display: none;" src="https://s5.gifyu.com/images/Loader5a73d3b26568dbc4.gif" alt="Loader5a73d3b26568dbc4.gif" border="0" />
    </div> <br />
}

<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <input id="submit" type="button" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="SendLoginData()" />
</div>
<label id="LoginErrorLabel" style="color: red; display: none;">*Wrong login detail !</label>
</div>
```

What I'm doing here is:

1) Send username&password to the 'CheckAccount' method in the controller, the method returns true/false.

2) If false, show label,
   if true, show gif image and send again the details to ActionResult (=AccountMainPage) which returns a new view.

I just wonder, is there a better/shorter way to do it using one post or one method? I heard something about the partial views in MVC, no idea what to do with it. People told me that what I did here is too old for MVC

Comment: well you could just post back to the CheckAccount endpoint (without AJAX) and have it issue a redirect to the Main page if the login is successful. Also, the way you're doing it now, you're actually posting the form twice - but the MainPage isn't interested in that data. You don't need those key fields to be inside a form. In fact you don't need a form at all, for your current approach. P.S. I assume the AccountMainPage verifies the user is logged in before it allows access to that page? Otherwise, it will be trivial to bypass your checking process.

Comment: Also, is there any reason you're not just using the built-in ASP.NET Identity services, rather than creating your own system?

Comment: I am beginner... No idea what is ASP.NET Identity services

Comment: that's what google is for... https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity . P.S. Normally when you create an MVC application from the template in Visual Studio it comes with some login and register pages created already...they are based on asp.net identity in the background. Use those, if you can. Or find a tutorial you can follow. e.g. something like https://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/mvc/securing-asp.net-mvc-applications-with-asp.net-identity.htm (for .NET Framework. If you're using .NET Core, find a different one).

Comment: Which one did you use,asp.net core mvc or asp.net mvc?